# Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, urlconnection

Is there any convenient way to read and parse data from incoming request.

E.g client initiate post request

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true); // true = autoFlush, important!
    // Send normal param.
    writer.println("--" + boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param\"");
    writer.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset);
    writer.println();
    writer.println(param);
```

I’m not able to get param using `request.getParameter("paramName")`. The following code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    request.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
   System.out.println(line);

  }
```

however displays the content for me

```
-----------------------------29772313742745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
J.Doe
-----------------------------29772313742745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
abuse@spamcop.com
-----------------------------29772313742745
```

What is the best way to parse incoming request? I don’t want to write my own parser, probably there is a  ready solution.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` encoded requests are indeed not by default supported by the Servlet API prior to version 3.0. The Servlet API parses the parameters by default using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. When using a different encoding, the `request.getParameter()` calls will all return `null`. When you're already on Servlet 3.0 or newer ([Glassfish 3](https://glassfish.org), [Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org), [WildFly](https://wildfly.org), etc, all introduced since December 2009 already), then you can use [`HttpServletRequest#getPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String)) instead. You can find elaboarate examples in [How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-can-i-upload-files-to-a-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Prior to Servlet 3.0, a [de facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) standard to parse `multipart/form-data` requests would be using [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/fileupload). You'll probably find answers and code examples using this library over all place on the Internet, but this is thus not needed anymore for more than 10 years already. Just use the standard `request.getPart(name)` method instead.

Comment: Be careful. Some of the documentation on the apache site is wrong. For example they says that you can call setRepository() on a FileItemFactory object which is false because any Object that implements FileItemFactory has only one method: createItem(). So be sure you read the javadocs as well.

Comment: `getParts()` always returns zero items. Why is it so hard to retrieve multipart forms in Java and Servlet 3.0? Can't believe it!

Comment: @basZero: the answer to the duplicate question already explains when it would be empty.

Comment: @BalusC do you have a link? It's quite a lot of info here on this page

Answer (score 16):

Solutions:

Solution A:

1. Download http://www.servlets.com/cos/index.html
2. Invoke getParameters() on `com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest`

Solution B:

1. Download http://jakarta.Apache.org/commons/fileupload/
2. Invoke readHeaders() in 
   `org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream`

Solution C:

1. Download http://users.boone.net/wbrameld/multipartformdata/
2. Invoke getParameter on 
   com.bigfoot.bugar.servlet.http.MultipartFormData

Solution D:

Use Struts. Struts 1.1 handles this automatically.

Reference: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1045507

Comment: Please put up some solutions as this links can get absolete any time in future. This will attract negative rating.

Answer (score 7):

Not always there's a servlet before of an upload (I could use a filter for example).
Or could be that the same controller ( again a filter or also a servelt ) can serve many actions, so I think that rely on that servlet configuration to use the getPart method (only for Servlet API >= 3.0), I don't know, I don't like.

In general, I prefer independent solutions, able to live alone, and in this case  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ is one of that.

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            //your operations on file
        } else {
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            String value = item.getString();
            //you operations on paramters
        }
}
```

Comment: it works only when you have a request object. But what in case of stream object or any other Object data?

Comment: The stream or any other object data will replace the request. So I would parse/read the stream or whatever  in order to get the multipart form data. Anyway do you have any real example?