# Get parameter from a POST

Tags: servlets, file-upload

Having a problem with a servlet posting from a form:

```
// index.jsp
<FORM ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='/test/uploadfile'>
  Your name: <input type="text" uploadername="name" /><br /> 
  <INPUT TYPE='file' NAME='filetoupload'>
  <INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='upload'>
</FORM>
```

---

```
// testservlet.java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String name = req.getParameter("uploadername");
    if (name == null || name.length() < 0) {
        // seems to always be empty.
    }
}
```

So yeah the `name` parameter never seems to be sent. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont know a thing about servlets however "name" is an html keyword try changing it to name1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It would seem that what you're trying to do isn't support by the servlet API prior to version 3.0. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet) for details and possible solutions.

Comment: This is entirely wrong and getting a form parameter is possible if you change the input element as I describe below. In the servlet req.getParameter should be request.getParameter.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
<input type="text" name="uploadername" />
```