# Java library for reading multipart/form-data http body containing multiple files

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, playframework, multipartform-data, httppostedfile

Basically, the following is what the format of data look like (it should follow HTTP standard format)

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f

--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo1.jpg"; filename="foo1.jpg"
Content-Length: 5578
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<image data 1 omitted>
--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo2.jpg"; filename="foo2.jpg"
Content-Length: 327
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<image data 2 omitted>
--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet) question which recommends using [Apache Commons File upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, unfortunately, HttpServletRequest is not exposed by Play! framework that has my web service hosted.

Comment: Apache Commons File Upload also includes classes for lower level processing (eg inputstream), so you might be able to use those.

Comment: Take a look at Play Framework 1.2.x source, they actually use Commons FileUpload to provide the users the form-data parts, and as @MarkRotteveel mentions you can find examples to read the data from a InputStream backed up by your body string data