# Why can't I get the formdata correctly on the server side?

Tags: javascript, jsp, multipartform-data

I have the following form with javascript that uploads a file to a server :

```
<h1>Upload Font</h1>                                                       
<form id="add" name="add" action="/font/add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="dialog">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name required">
            <label for="description">Font Description:</label>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" name="font.description" size="44" value="" id="name"/>      
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name required">
            <label for="description">Font File:</label>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="62" value="" id="fname" onchange="fileUpload('/pages/font/getFontTitle.jsp',value,this.files[0])"/>
          </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr class="prop">
          <td>
            <span class="button"><div align="right" id="wwctrl_add_0"><input type="submit" id="add_0" value="Submit"/></div></span>
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function fileUpload(url,fileName,fileData)
  {
    try
    {    
      var fileSize=fileData.size;
alert('fileSize : '+fileSize); 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");                       // code for IE6, IE5 
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) document.getElementById('name').value=xmlhttp.responseText; }
      xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
      var formdata=new FormData();
      formdata.append('fileName',fileName);
      formdata.append('file',fileData);
      xmlhttp.send(formdata);
    }
    catch(e) { alert(e.message); }
  }
</script>
```

My program getFontTitle.jsp on the server side look like this :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.*" %>

<%
  String contentType=request.getContentType(),Location="0.",                   // To get the content type information from JSP Request Header
             fontAttributes="",fontTitle="";
System.out.println("contentType = "+contentType);
  if ((contentType!=null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0))  // Here we are checking the content type is not equal to Null and as well as the passed data from mulitpart/form-data is greater than or equal to 0
  {
Location+="1.";
    try
    {
      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
      int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();                           // We are taking the length of Content type data
      byte dataBytes[]=new byte[formDataLength];
      int byteRead=0;
      int totalBytesRead=0;

      while (totalBytesRead<formDataLength)                                    // This loop converting the uploaded file into byte code
      {
        byteRead=in.read(dataBytes,totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
        totalBytesRead+=byteRead;
      }
System.out.println("dataBytes : "+dataBytes.length+"\n"+dataBytes.toString());

      String file=new String(dataBytes);
System.out.println("file = \n"+file);
System.out.println("file.length = "+file.length());

System.out.println("file.indexOf(filename=) = "+file.indexOf("filename=\""));
String saveFile=file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"")+10);          // For saving the file name
      Location+="2.";
      saveFile=saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
System.out.println("saveFile = "+saveFile);
      Location+="3.";
      saveFile=saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
      Location+="4.";
      int lastIndex=contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
      Location+="5.";
      String boundary=contentType.substring(lastIndex+1,contentType.length());
System.out.println(" boundary = "+boundary);
      int pos;
      Location+="6.";
      pos=file.indexOf("filename=\"");                                         // Extracting the index of file 
      Location+="7.";
      pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
      pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
      pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
      Location+="8.";
      int boundaryLocation=file.indexOf(boundary,pos)-4;
      System.out.println(" boundaryLocation = "+boundaryLocation+"  filename = "+file.indexOf("filename=\""));
      int startPos=((file.substring(0,pos)).getBytes()).length;
      int endPos=((file.substring(0,boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
      System.out.println(" startPos = "+startPos+" , endPos = "+endPos);

      Location+="9.";
      File f=new File(saveFile);
      FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream(f);
//      fileOut.write(dataBytes,startPos,(endPos-startPos));
      fileOut.write(dataBytes);
      fileOut.flush();
      fileOut.close();

Location+="a.";
//      System.out.println("================================\nstartPos = "+startPos+" , endPos = "+endPos+"\nf = "+f+"\nf.getAbsolutePath() = "+f.getAbsolutePath()+"\n\n=== contentType ===\n\n"+contentType+"\n\n=== file ===\n\n"+file+"\n================================");
//    out.println(f+"<Br>"+file);
Location+="b.";
      Font createdFont=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,new FileInputStream(f));
Location+="c.";

//      System.out.println(createdFont);
Location+="d.";
      fontAttributes=createdFont.getAttributes().toString();                   // map of {family="A.C.M.E. Explosive Bold", weight=1.0*, width=1.0*, posture=0.0*, size=1.0, transform=null*, superscript=0*, tracking=0.0*[btx=null, ctx=null]}
      System.out.println(fontAttributes);
      fontTitle=fontAttributes.substring(fontAttributes.indexOf("\"")+1,fontAttributes.lastIndexOf("\""));
      out.println(fontTitle);
Location+="e.";

//      out.println("Done : "+saveFile);

    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
Location+="f.";
  }
  else if (contentType==null) out.println("Not a valid file");
  out.println(" [ "+Location+" ]");

  out.flush();

%>

The output look like this : [ 0.1.2.f. ]
There is error on line : saveFile=saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
There is no index of saveFile.indexOf("\n")
What did I do wrong ? Maybe it's not getting the data in the correct format ?
```

==========================================

I've changed the code to use FileUpload, it looks like this :

```
<%
  String contentType=request.getContentType(),Location="0.",                   // To get the content type information from JSP Request Header
             fontAttributes="",fontTitle="";
out.println("Done");
System.out.println("contentType = "+contentType);

  boolean isMultipart=ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);           // Check that we have a file upload request
  System.out.println("isMultipart = "+isMultipart);

  FileItemFactory factory=new DiskFileItemFactory();                           // Create a factory for disk-based file items
  ServletFileUpload upload=new ServletFileUpload(factory);                     // Create a new file upload handler
  List /* FileItem */ items=upload.parseRequest(request);                      // Parse the request

  Iterator iter=items.iterator();                                              // Process the uploaded items
  while (iter.hasNext())
  {
    FileItem item=(FileItem) iter.next();
    if (item.isFormField())                                                    // Process a regular form field
    {
        String name=item.getFieldName();
      String value=item.getString();
      System.out.println("name = "+name+"  value = "+value);
    }
    else
    {
      String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
      String fileName = item.getName();
      contentType = item.getContentType();
      boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
      long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();
      System.out.println("isInMemory = "+isInMemory+"  sizeInBytes = "+sizeInBytes);

    }
  }

  if ((contentType!=null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0))  // Here we are checking the content type is not equal to Null and as well as the passed data from mulitpart/form-data is greater than or equal to 0
  {
Location+="1.";
    try
    {
      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
      int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();                           // We are taking the length of Content type data
      byte dataBytes[]=new byte[formDataLength];
      int byteRead=0;
      int totalBytesRead=0;

      while (totalBytesRead<formDataLength)                                    // This loop converting the uploaded file into byte code
      {
        byteRead=in.read(dataBytes,totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
        totalBytesRead+=byteRead;
      }
System.out.println("dataBytes : "+dataBytes.length+"\n"+dataBytes.toString());
```

....

```
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
Location+="f.";
  }
  else if (contentType==null) out.println("Not a valid file");
  out.println(" [ "+Location+" ]");

  out.flush();

%>
```

The output is :

```
contentType = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------184228830106
isMultipart = true
dataBytes : 35918
[B@1c8365b
file =

file.length = 35918
file.indexOf(filename=) = -1
```

Comment: do you read the file correctly?

Comment: What Servlet version do you use? 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: I would recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet and more specifically use http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Comment: @MaVRoSCy : I've changed my program to use FileUpload, but still get nothing, yet the file size on the server side seems correct, just could not find the boundary, see my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry for my commends, i did not realize that you where doing the uploading using ajax (i though it was a simple post) . Simply it is not supported but most browsers ( [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) ). Using later versions of Chrome and Mozilla this might be possible though ( [jQuery Upload Progress and AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload/4943774#4943774) )

You can achieve a cross browser functionality for files uploading by submitting a hidden iframe (this technique is the de facto implementation of ajax file uploading).

There are also some ready made plugins such as http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/ and https://github.com/valums/file-uploader that you can find usefull