# HTML upload file with Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, file-upload

I need to upload a file by HTML but my form request has to include other parameters and values, for this i made the following:

I have the following html form:

```
<form action="CustomerAccountingServlet" method="post" name="payment_list_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="123"/>
<input type="hidden" name="payment_id" value="444" />
<input type="file" name="invoice_file" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form
```

I use the following java code to get the file:

```
public static InputStream uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request, String fileFieldName) {

        int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
        int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

        // Verify the content type
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            // maximum size that will be stored in memory
            factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
            // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
            factory.setRepository(new File(filePath));

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            // maximum file size to be uploaded.
            upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
            upload.setHeaderEncoding("utf-8");
            try {
                // Parse the request to get file items.
                List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                // Process the uploaded file items
                Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                    if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                        if(fi.getFieldName().equals(fileFieldName)){
                            return fi.getInputStream();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file was found");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem that i get null when i do in the servlet the following:

```
request.getParameter("action");
request.getParameter("customer_id");
request.getParameter("payment_id");
```

Anyone can help please?
Thanks!

Comment: The missing `>` at the end of the `</form` is just a typo, right?

Comment: Have a look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference request parameters for multipart/form-data request in the conventional way. All the parameters are encoded in the multipart data, along with the uploaded file. See for example [this blog post](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html) for an extended example of how this should be handled.

Comment: Thank you, helped very much. I used the following: ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
// maximum file size to be uploaded.
upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
// Parse the request to get file items.
List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);