# Javascript adding hidden data to form

Tags: javascript

I've the following `Javascript` function to add `invisible` data into my form,

```
function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = key;'name-as-seen-at-the-server';
input.value = value;
theForm.appendChild(input);
}
```

and I have **two forms as follows**

**form1**

```
<form method="get" id="execform" name="toexecute" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="to execute">
        <ul id=ul>
            <li><button type= "button" id="execute1" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Click to execute</button></li><li><br></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**saveTextAsFile()**

```
var script = ace.edit("editor");
var myDivText = script.getValue();
var theForm = document.forms['toexecute'];
addHidden(theForm, 'mytxt', myDivText);
document.toexecute.submit();
```

**form2**

```
<form method="post" id="theform" name="myform" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="elements">
    <ul id="ul">
        <li>Left File : <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li>Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li>Runner.xlsx : <input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li><button type="button" id="execute" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ValidateFile()**

```
var myDivText1 = ace.edit("editor").getValue();
var theForm1 = document.forms['myform'];
addHidden(theForm1, 'mytxt1', myDivText1);
alert(myDivText1);
document.myform.submit();
```

The hidden data of **form 1** is being successfully added, passed and I am able to access that in my servlet, while I've used the same method in **form 2** my servlet is throwing a `nullpointerexception`. What is my mistake?

When **form2** is being submitted in my servlet,

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{//activated by the form named myform of line 93 in geco.jsp
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    String fpath= null;
    if (cookies != null) {//Get cookie initilised when user uploads geco script
     for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
       if (cookie.getName().equals("thecookie")) { 
           fpath = cookie.getValue();
        }
      }
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html");  

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try 
        {  
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);  
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {  
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();  
                if (!item.isFormField())  
                {
                    String fileName = item.getName();      

                         String itemField = item.getFieldName();

                         if (itemField.equals("dataFile1")) 
                         {  //get the text of the editor here and save it

                            String TEXT = request.getAttribute("mytxt1").toString();//This is where it is displaying null


                            File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
                            item.write(uploadedFile);
                            String f1 = "<span class='blue'>" + "Uploaded <b>left file</b> " +fileName+ "<br>" + "</span>";
                            request.setAttribute("f1stat", f1);
                         }
                         if (itemField.equals("dataFile2"))
                         {    
                            File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
                            item.write(uploadedFile);
                            String f2 = "<span class='blue'>" +"Uploaded <b>right file</b> " +fileName+ "<br>" + "</span>";

                            request.setAttribute("f2stat", f2);
                         }
                         if (itemField.equals("dataFile3"))
                         {
                             File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
                             item.write(uploadedFile);
                             File uploadedFile1 = new File(fpath, "Runner.xlsx");
                             item.write(uploadedFile1);
                             String f3 = "<span class='blue'>" +"Uploaded <b>Config file</b> " +fileName+ "<br>" + "</span>";
                             request.setAttribute("f3stat", f3);

                             String content="";
                             if(new File(fpath).exists())
                                {
                                    String my = fpath + "/gecofile.geco";

                                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(my));
                                        String line1;
                                        while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                                            {
                                                content= content + line1 +"\n";
                                            }
                                }
                             request.setAttribute("File_Text", content);
                             RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("geco");
                             rd.forward(request, response); 
                         }
```

PS: The cookie is set when **form1** is submitted to doGet() and here in doPost() I am accessing the same cookie value.

**PS:** I've tried changing `getAttribute` to `getParameter` still the value remains null.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `document.forms['myform']` is holding a reference to your form?

Comment: @Askanison4 there's no doubt. see form's name.

Comment: Yep and thats the only form with that name I have

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Actually these are parts of my program, and so adding a fiddle would be of no use without the servlet side code

Comment: have you checked that your hidden field value is passed from client to servlet ?

Comment: Why don't you try adding a breakpoint before you submit and check the DOM for the form and the fields there. See if it has been added?

Comment: Yep, on the client side the alert displays the correct value but on the server side it is being showed as a null value

Comment: @Zedai I don't mean the alert... you know the value being passed into your `addHidden` function is correct. I mean that you should inspect the actual HTML generated and be sure that the hidden input is being added to your form.

Comment: Make the added input not hidden, so you can actually see what is happening. And if it works correct, make it hidden again.

Comment: added servlet code, pl check everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input field adds properly. Check request with **FireBug** if the data from hidden input is there, it should be. It is rather your servlet issue. Maybe because you use different names for the forms. Maybe because you give different values for `input.name` . Code above works fine. The reason might be also in that your first form `toexecute` does have no action field.

You give us to little data about server side code to solve this problem.

EDIT:

I don't have experience in Java Servlets so I'm just shooting. At first time you send **GET** and `request.getAttribute()` works. Second time you send **POST**, and there is issue with that. Since you send images, that is encoded data, you can't read it normally. I think you will find your answer here:

[HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data)

EDIT2:

Try this method. It should do the job:

```
request.getServletContext().getAttribute("attr_name");
```

EDIT3:

Because you're using **Tomcat 6**, you have issue with hadling `multipart/form-data`. Here is similiar problem and solution:

[Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)

You should move to **Tomcat 7**.

Comment: What version of Tomcat or Glassfish are you using?

Comment: Hey I'm using tomcat 6

Answer (score 0):

Inside your servlet you need to be getting the request *parameter* called `mytxt1` not an attribute set in the request with that name (unless there's some code you haven't shown us). Change this line:

```
String TEXT = request.getAttribute("mytxt1").toString();//This is where it is displaying null
```

to

```
String TEXT = request.getParameter("mytxt1");
```

Comment: Tried both, still the value is null

Comment: @Zedai And you're sure the hidden input is being added correctly by the JavaScript? Try taking out the line that submits the form and checking that.

Comment: @Zedai As I said before, you cannot use standard functions to read data when you send encoded data. Normal post is send like string or array. Images require to send encoded objects and you cannot read them as usual. Object that usually stores data is empty.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think they are not being added properly as I see no chamge in the URL during my second form submit