# Decoding HTML form data in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, post

I had an issue while working,

Let's say I had to get a client's file uploaded, so I was using

```
<form action='UploadFile.jsp' method='post' enctype='multiform/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='data' id='filechooser'>
</form>
```

Things were fine till I needed to add some more details to the form

now the form contained 2 more input tags,

```
<form action='UploadFile.jsp' method='post' enctype='multiform/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='data' id='filechooser'>
  <input type='number' name='no_of_days'/>
  <input type='date' name='dat'/>
</form>
```

Now the other two elements are showing null when i access them using request.getParameter() method.

I was using UploadFile from [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm&ei=3Pd6U_KUDtaNuATwsIGACQ&usg=AFQjCNHjhUVchyytc5Ytp9fG3Z1pFME0oQ&sig2=nIW4q4aEBdM4CzMke7j3Dg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.c2E) tutorial

**What I have tried?**

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) question that was not similar but had a seemingly correct answer and tried the answer but i keep getting NullReferenceException for this line

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(part.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

This line of code is the part of answer in the above linked question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet

check this possibly the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `Commons` library (which I believe you are because of the link you've mentioned in your question) - You can get the simple parameters simply:

the `FileItem` class has a method called `isFormField` which will return true if this Item represents a simple form field. Once you know a specific `FileItem` is a simple form field, you can use `getFieldName` and `getString` to get the name/value for this field.

Basically, if you used the code from the example you've mentioned, you can do the following:

```
if (!fi.isFormField ()) {
    // Get the uploaded file parameters
    ..... code for file field ....
} else {
    //it's a simple form field - get it's name and value and do whatever you need    
    String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
    String fieldValue = fi.getString();
}
```