# Encountering an error when uploading an image

Tags: mysql, image, jsp, upload

I am trying to upload an image to my database using jsp. I want to store the image in a folder called `Upload` and want to insert the image name in the database. I used a servlet to do this.
I uses seperate pages for input, action and database connection and I explain the code below.

```
Photo.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body><form name="f" action="uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr><td>
            Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td> Address</td><td><textarea name="addr" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr> <td><input type="file" name="f1"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="b1"></td></tr></table> </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

My database connection is given below:

```
public int insert_file(String name, String addr, String img) 
{
    int i=0;
    System.out.println("inside insert_file");
    try
    {
        Connection con21=get_con();
        System.out.print(con21);
        Statement s21=con21.createStatement();
        String s11="insert into image(name,addr,image) values ('"+name+"','"+addr+"','"+img+"')";
        System.out.println("i"+s11);
        i=s21.executeUpdate(s11);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Here is my servlet page:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import DBConnection.MYConnection;

/**
 *
 * @author MONOOS
 */
@WebServlet(name = "uploadimage", urlPatterns = {"/uploadimage"})
public class uploadimage extends HttpServlet {
String name,addr,img;
//MYConnection obj=new MYConnection();


    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        MYConnection obj=new MYConnection();
        out.println(obj);
        out.println("haiiii");
        try {
            out.println("inside try");
            System.out.print("inside try");
        List fileItems;


        // Parsing field values
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        out.println(factory);
        factory.setSizeThreshold(10000000);

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        // maximum file size to be uploaded.
        upload.setSizeMax(10000000);

        try {
            // Parse the request to get file items.
            out.println("inside nested try");
            fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

            // Process the uploaded file items
            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
            out.println(i);
            while (i.hasNext()) {

                FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();

                if (fi.isFormField()) {
                     if (fi.getFieldName().equals("name")) {                        
                        name = fi.getString();
                        out.println(name);;
                        System.out.println("name:"+name);
                    }
                      if (fi.getFieldName().equals("addr"))
                      {                        
                        addr = fi.getString();
                        System.out.println("address:"+addr);
                        out.println(addr);
                      }
                }

                    else 
                   {
                       out.println("inside else");
                   System.out.println("inside else");
                   img = fi.getName();
                   System.out.println("Image :"+img);
                    File outfile = new File("I:\\NetBeansProjects\\MGNREGA\\web\\Upload" + fi.getName());
                    fi.write(outfile);
                }
            }

            int j=obj.insert_file("nayana","gfg",img);
            System.out.println("j:" + j);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.print(e);
        }
     }
        finally {            
            out.close();
        }

    }// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

My problem is that the code is running, but it does not do what I want. The first print statement in the try clause are printed successfully.

Comment: Is there a error message or exceptio trace?

Comment: No not at all. I didnt get an error. but its not working

Comment: You are using multipart form, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet

Comment: What does System.out.println("Image :"+img);  print? You should post all your debug statements that print.

Comment: sorry i can't understand you..

Comment: Are you talking about my comment?

Comment: The control does not enter at that block.It does not print anything...

Comment: it only prints the first three out.println statements. it does not enter into the while block

Comment: Replace finally block with a catch. In both catches you should use printStackTrace().

Comment: it does not print anything

Comment: You should use your debug print statements to see where your code is failing. Print out each step. The first step would be to print whether the request is good. To do that use; boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

Comment: Is printed as true. But the error is "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem"

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem... I change the package "import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;" into "import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;".
now it running well....