# While using Part.getPart() method Servlet is throwing an ServletException

Tags: java, servlets

I have written servlet code to upload photo to my database and when I run the page and try to upload photo I'm getting Exception at this point

`Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");`

where photo is name is given to input field in my form and the code for that is

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">
```

and the Exception report shown by Apache tomcat in the browser is

```
type: Exception report

message: Servlet execution threw an exception

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part;

      Uploaddp.doPost(Uploaddp.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Full stack trace

```
Sep 29, 2016 3:44:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Uploaddp threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part;
    at Uploaddp.doPost(Uploaddp.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Add the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

there is no type as "file". you need to use multpart/form-data. For more refer to this post 
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)
Also, to fetch this file at server side you need to use some library as explained here
[Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)
Also, take into considerations like where will you store these files on server after processing. Users might like to download uploaded images. Also, security around accessibility of these files.