# How does submitting form using action attribute differ from sending form data using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to submit my form values using XMLHttpRequest.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="../myapi/submitRequest">
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type">
    <input type="text" name="eventDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <input type="file" name="reciept">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Somewhere in Java:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("type"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("eventDate"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("amount"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("reciept"));
```

This prints the form fields value. Works perfectly!

**But,**

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type">
    <input type="text" name="eventDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <input type="file" name="reciept">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","../myapi/submitRequest",true);

    let fd = new FormData(form);

    xhr.send(fd);

});
```

Somewhere in Java:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("type"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("eventDate"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("amount"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("reciept"));
```

When I do this, I get **null** for all parameter values.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: change xhr.open("POST","../myapi/submitRequest",true); to xhr.open("POST","/myapi/submitRequest",true);

Comment: .. is considered as part of the url when you give in javascript

Comment: @deepakthomas That was intentional. If i don't do that i get a 404 error code

Comment: what does the network request show?? does it have the parameter in the payload

Comment: Does your page refresh when you click on submit button ? Because you don't have any code to prevent that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out why it was acting this way. When I was submitting the form data using the `action` attribute, I did not set the `enctype` attribute. So, when I was submitting the form, the content type was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And when I was sending it using javascript, the content type was set to `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfxmNAuz7ZhhuUcZn`.

I looked around and found out that request.getParameter() will return null if the content-type is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So, that was why I was getting those null values!

#### Helpful Posts

[Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)